# Warning: Return value of low-level calls not used. --> hh.sol:147:6: | 147 | payable(0xdF3e18d64BC6A983f673Ab319CCaE4f1a57C7097 )

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

[image]

I want to share profit between different wallets. The contract is working and the profit is divided but I get that message that make me feel uncomfortable, and I can't find why. Could you please help me? Thanks.

```
function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
// This will pay HashLips 5% of the initial sale.
// You can remove this if you want, or keep it in to support HashLips and his channel.
// =============================================================================
(bool hs, ) =
 payable(0xFCAB2804fe7E1eeF2497Fc861aD238B3c80c8325 ).call{value: address(this).balance * 35 / 100}("");
 payable(0xdF3e18d64BC6A983f673Ab319CCaE4f1a57C7097 ).call{value: address(this).balance * 15 / 100}("");
 payable(0xbDA5747bFD65F08deb54cb465eB87D40e51B197E ).call{value: address(this).balance * 5 / 100}
("");

require(hs);
// =============================================================================
// This will transfer the remaining contract balance to the owner.
// Do not remove this otherwise you will not be able to withdraw the funds.
// =============================================================================
(bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
// ===========================================**
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(bool hs, ) = 
  payable(0xFCAB2804fe7E1eeF2497Fc861aD238B3c80c8325 ).call{value: address(this).balance * 35 / 100}("");
  payable(0xdF3e18d64BC6A983f673Ab319CCaE4f1a57C7097 ).call{value: address(this).balance * 15 / 100}("");
  payable(0xbDA5747bFD65F08deb54cb465eB87D40e51B197E ).call{value: address(this).balance * 5 / 100}
("");
```

In this snippet you are making three separate instructions. The value `bool hs` is the return value of only the first call, so the compiler gives you warnings for the second and third calls.

I suggest rewriting the code with a cleaner syntax first, so it's easier to understand.

```
(bool hs, ) = payable(0xFCAB2804fe7E1eeF2497Fc861aD238B3c80c8325).call{value: address(this).balance * 35 / 100}("");
payable(0xdF3e18d64BC6A983f673Ab319CCaE4f1a57C7097).call{value: address(this).balance * 15 / 100}("");
payable(0xbDA5747bFD65F08deb54cb465eB87D40e51B197E).call{value: address(this).balance * 5 / 100}("");
```

The fix consists of getting the boolean return value for every call, and requiring it to be `true`.

```
bool hs;
(hs, ) = payable(0xFCAB2804fe7E1eeF2497Fc861aD238B3c80c8325).call{value: address(this).balance * 35 / 100}("");
require(hs);
(hs, ) = payable(0xdF3e18d64BC6A983f673Ab319CCaE4f1a57C7097).call{value: address(this).balance * 15 / 100}("");
require(hs);
(hs, ) = payable(0xbDA5747bFD65F08deb54cb465eB87D40e51B197E).call{value: address(this).balance * 5 / 100}("");
require(hs);
```

Without the require statements, an internal function may revert without reverting the entire transaction.

(Unrelated) Also you need to know that `address(this).balance` decreases in value for every call: for example if it starts at `100 ETH`, the first address gets `35 ETH`, the second `(100-35)*15% = 9.75 ETH`, etc...
If this is unintentional, you have to save the starting balance and use that, like this:

```
uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
bool hs;
(hs, ) = payable(...).call{value: balance * 35 / 100}("");
require(hs);
(hs, ) = payable(...).call{value: balance * 15 / 100}("");
require(hs);
// etc..
```

Comment: HI Riccardo Thanks for you help,i think what you said about Msg,sender is crucial may i know what should i do to make the repartition follow the logic im trying to do.i mean to divide parts equally for all contributor's wallets.what im trying to achieve is to give the owner 45 percent and divide the rest btw others wallet

Comment: @onemintspot I added a way to to it in the answer

Comment: yeah THANK YOU i think the first one is working like a charm for me as i only have to lower the percentage to get the same value that all artists agree with last thing please i got this error  but everything else is working smoothly .as you can see after declaring the error now appears in msg.sender line when i tried some tricks the money doesnt withdraw.


Warning: Unused local variable.
--> hh.sol:138:6:
|
138 | (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
| ^^^^^^^

Comment: yeah you need to add a `require(os)` after that line. Basically every "low-level" call returns a boolean that states if the call was successful or not; so you have to add the "require" yourself. The compiler gave you the warning that you declared that variable without using it